# Unit Test custom Zend_Form element

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework

This is a long winded question but I've spent hours searching and trying different things but haven't gotten it solved yet so this is my last hope.

I've created a custom Zend_Form_Element which I got the code from here: http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/ All the code can be found on that site but basically I've created a form which has multiple input elements which returns one value.

Doing a view source on the resulting webpage, the form element will look like this

```
<input size="3" maxlength="3" id="phone-areanum" name="phone[areanum]" value="" type="text">
<input size="3" maxlength="3" id="phone-geonum" name="phone[geonum]" value="" type="text">
<input size="4" maxlength="4" id="phone-localnum" name="phone[localnum]" value="" type="text">
```

Here is the unit test which I feel should work but isn't

```
    public function testValidDataRedirectsToAppointmentTimePage()
{
    $phone = array('areanum'=>'480', 'geonum'=>'123', 'localnum'=>'5678' );
    $this->request->setMethod('post')
                  ->setPost(array(
                    'phone' => $phone,
                    'name' => 'Smith'
                  ));
    $this->dispatch('/sign-in');


    // assert that user was redirected to current-patient page
    $this->assertRedirectTo('/current-patient');
}
```

I'm testing that if the user enters their phone number and name into the fields they'll get redirected to the right page. When I stuck a `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getResponse()->getBody());` into the unit test function I was able to determine that the value I set in post caused an error and the page didn't load correctly. 
Other values I've tried for $phone are:

```
$phone = array('480', '123', '5678');
$phone = array( 480, 123, 5678 );
$phone = '480-123-5678';
$phone = '4801235678';
```

Can't think of what else there is to try?

Update: Adding Controller Action

```
public function phoneAction()
{
    $this->view->title = "Please Sign In"; 
    $this->view->headTitle("Sign In");
    $form = new Application_Form_Phone();

    $this->view->form = $form;

    if( $this->getRequest()->isPost() ) {
        if( $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) ) {
            $phone = $form->getValue('phone');
            $name = $form->getValue('name');

            // function to get user's id from their info
            $this->_session->user_id = $this->_getUserId($phone, $name);

            return $this->_redirect('/current-patient');
        }
    }
}

class Application_Form_Phone extends Zend_Dojo_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElementPrefixPath('Grabby_Form_Validate', 'Grabby/Form/Validate', 'validate');
        $this->setName('phoneform');
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $phone = new Grabby_Form_Element_Phone('phone');
        $phone->addValidator(new Grabby_Form_Validate_Phone());
        $this->addElement($phone);

        $this->addElement('ValidationTextBox', 'name', array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Last Name',
            'trim' => true,
            'promptMessage' =>'Enter your last name',
            'InvalidMessage' => 'Last name required',
        ));

        $this->addElement('SubmitButton', 'submitbutton', array(
            'label' => 'Submit',
            'ignore' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

As you can see there is not much going on. The code works fine, just trying to unit-test it so I can "prove" it works.

Comment: could you please post the controller / form code? thanks

Comment: Technically, this probably isn't unit-testing the _element_, but testing the element, the form, and the controller all together. Perhaps a narrower unit-test focused on the element itself? See the [form element unit-tests](http://framework.zend.com/code/listing.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2FZend%2FForm%2FElement%2F&#a99e5f5c78a10fd004ba3f5b1f5c641c9) for examples.

Comment: @DavidWeinraub You are correct. I'm trying to test the element, form, and controller together. I'm new to unit testing so that made the most "sense" to me. Thanks for the link, seeing other unit-tests will definitely be helpful for me.

Comment: Uhm, you are dispatching "$this->dispatch('/sign-in');
" not phoneAction?

Comment: @ArneRie Sorry, I should have mentioned this earlier. In my application.ini file I set a custom route to set "/sign-in" to the phone action.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably something along these lines:

```
$phone = array(
    'areanum' => 480,
    'geonum' => 123,
    'localnum' => 5678
);
```

Although you create a combined value in the end, the post still sends it split into parts.